# How can I recover bookmarks in firefox

Tags: 10.10, firefox, data-recovery, bookmarks

I have Firefox on Ubuntu 10.10.  I added another profile to Firefox  in the last two weeks.  Firefox gave me the option to choose between the different profiles, but now it will not login automatically.  So how can I restore bookmarks or the other profile for Firefox.  Any suggestion will be appreciated.

Comment: my another profile maybe has deleted how can i recover it .

Comment: look at the bottom of my answer.  I have updated it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to choose which profile to start.  The way to do so

Just press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> on your keyboard to open Terminal. When it opens, run the command below.

```
firefox -P
```

[image]

and make sure that you do not have a check mark in ***Don`t ask at startup***

Now, to restore your bookmarks, or copy the old profile to the new profile, do this:

Go into the original profile, press

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>O</kbd> on your keyboard to open the bookmark window

[image]

click on Import and Backup, and choose Backup

[image]

Then choose the file name and location of the file.

[image]

Now, to restore the bookmarks, follow the same steps, but instead of Backup, choose Restore, and pick the file that you backed up

[image]

To recover a deleted profile:

Using the Profile Manager to recover a profile

If another profile folder exists with data you want to recover, you can use the Profile Manager to create a new profile that will use the profile folder containing your missing data.  For complete information [See this site](http://kb.mozillazine.org/Recovering_a_missing_profile)

Comment: thanks for your help Mr.Mitch ,but my another profile doesn't appear in one step .please how can i recover deleted profile?

Answer (score 2):

1. Press `Ctrl+Shift+o`
2. In the Bookmarks window choose the last menu item (Imports), and there Restore.

(I don't use English version, I hope that the menu names are correct.)